# Where to save Yelp files?

Tags: packaging, yelp

I've written some yelp pages using [Mallard](http://projectmallard.org/about/learn/index.html). Now I would like to know where to
save them correctly in the file system (packaging). The saved Yelp files should be
displayed when opening `Yelp -> Go -> All Documents` too.

Addition:
It's kind hard to find information about that kind of stuff. Do you know a good
place where to find such information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Yelp to find your application's help pages, they should be installed under:

`/usr/share/gnome/help/$app_name/$locale/`

As for where to find this information... Well, you're right. I don't see this clearly documented anywhere. [GNOME Handbook of Writing Software Documentation](http://alien.cern.ch/cache/libxslt-1.0.10/tests/docbook/result/xtchunk/html/index.orig) does include a [section](http://developer.gnome.org/gdp-handbook/stable/buildingdocs.html.en) that includes information on how to incorporate it into the build system, but it assumes that you are using autotools.

I usually just look at examples that I have installed on my system. For instance, I can see that Totem shows up in `Yelp -> Go -> All Documents`. So let's see where it installs its documentation:

```
$ dpkg -L totem-common | grep "help"
/usr/share/gnome/help
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/cs
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/cs/figures
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/gl
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/gl/figures
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/pa
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/pa/figures
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/fi
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/fi/figures
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/pl
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/pl/figures
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/zh_CN
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/zh_CN/figures
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/uk
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/uk/figures
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/pt_BR
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/pt_BR/figures
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/zh_HK
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/zh_HK/figures
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/eu
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/eu/figures
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/C
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/C/totem.xml
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/C/figures
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/C/figures/totem_show_playlist_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/C/figures/totem_next_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/C/figures/totem_volume_mute_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/C/figures/totem_volume_maximum_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/C/figures/totem_previous_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/C/figures/totem_start_window.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/C/figures/totem_play_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/C/figures/totem_pause_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/C/legal.xml
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/ca
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/ca/figures
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/sl
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/sl/figures
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/it
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/it/figures
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/zh_TW
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/zh_TW/figures
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/te
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/te/figures
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/ja
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/ja/figures
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/de
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/de/figures
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/bg
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/bg/figures
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/el
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/el/figures
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/ru
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/ru/figures
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/oc
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/oc/figures
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/fr
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/fr/figures
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/en_GB
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/en_GB/figures
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/es
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/es/figures
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/sv
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/sv/figures
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/ro
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/ro/figures
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/da
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/da/figures
/usr/share/gtk-doc/html/totem/totem.devhelp2
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/cs/totem.xml
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/cs/figures/totem_show_playlist_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/cs/figures/totem_next_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/cs/figures/totem_volume_mute_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/cs/figures/totem_volume_maximum_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/cs/figures/totem_previous_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/cs/figures/totem_start_window.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/cs/figures/totem_play_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/cs/figures/totem_pause_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/gl/totem.xml
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/gl/figures/totem_show_playlist_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/gl/figures/totem_next_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/gl/figures/totem_volume_mute_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/gl/figures/totem_volume_maximum_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/gl/figures/totem_previous_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/gl/figures/totem_start_window.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/gl/figures/totem_play_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/gl/figures/totem_pause_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/pa/totem.xml
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/pa/figures/totem_show_playlist_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/pa/figures/totem_next_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/pa/figures/totem_volume_mute_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/pa/figures/totem_volume_maximum_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/pa/figures/totem_previous_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/pa/figures/totem_start_window.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/pa/figures/totem_play_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/pa/figures/totem_pause_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/fi/totem.xml
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/fi/figures/totem_show_playlist_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/fi/figures/totem_next_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/fi/figures/totem_volume_mute_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/fi/figures/totem_volume_maximum_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/fi/figures/totem_previous_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/fi/figures/totem_start_window.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/fi/figures/totem_play_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/fi/figures/totem_pause_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/pl/totem.xml
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/pl/figures/totem_show_playlist_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/pl/figures/totem_next_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/pl/figures/totem_volume_mute_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/pl/figures/totem_volume_maximum_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/pl/figures/totem_previous_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/pl/figures/totem_start_window.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/pl/figures/totem_play_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/pl/figures/totem_pause_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/zh_CN/totem.xml
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/zh_CN/figures/totem_show_playlist_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/zh_CN/figures/totem_next_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/zh_CN/figures/totem_volume_mute_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/zh_CN/figures/totem_volume_maximum_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/zh_CN/figures/totem_previous_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/zh_CN/figures/totem_start_window.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/zh_CN/figures/totem_play_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/zh_CN/figures/totem_pause_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/uk/totem.xml
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/uk/figures/totem_show_playlist_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/uk/figures/totem_next_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/uk/figures/totem_volume_mute_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/uk/figures/totem_volume_maximum_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/uk/figures/totem_previous_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/uk/figures/totem_start_window.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/uk/figures/totem_play_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/uk/figures/totem_pause_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/pt_BR/totem.xml
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/pt_BR/figures/totem_show_playlist_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/pt_BR/figures/totem_next_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/pt_BR/figures/totem_volume_mute_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/pt_BR/figures/totem_volume_maximum_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/pt_BR/figures/totem_previous_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/pt_BR/figures/totem_start_window.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/pt_BR/figures/totem_play_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/pt_BR/figures/totem_pause_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/zh_HK/totem.xml
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/zh_HK/figures/totem_show_playlist_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/zh_HK/figures/totem_next_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/zh_HK/figures/totem_volume_mute_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/zh_HK/figures/totem_volume_maximum_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/zh_HK/figures/totem_previous_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/zh_HK/figures/totem_start_window.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/zh_HK/figures/totem_play_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/zh_HK/figures/totem_pause_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/eu/totem.xml
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/eu/figures/totem_show_playlist_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/eu/figures/totem_next_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/eu/figures/totem_volume_mute_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/eu/figures/totem_volume_maximum_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/eu/figures/totem_previous_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/eu/figures/totem_start_window.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/eu/figures/totem_play_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/eu/figures/totem_pause_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/ca/totem.xml
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/ca/figures/totem_show_playlist_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/ca/figures/totem_next_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/ca/figures/totem_volume_mute_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/ca/figures/totem_volume_maximum_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/ca/figures/totem_previous_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/ca/figures/totem_start_window.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/ca/figures/totem_play_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/ca/figures/totem_pause_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/sl/totem.xml
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/sl/figures/totem_show_playlist_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/sl/figures/totem_next_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/sl/figures/totem_volume_mute_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/sl/figures/totem_volume_maximum_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/sl/figures/totem_previous_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/sl/figures/totem_start_window.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/sl/figures/totem_play_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/sl/figures/totem_pause_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/it/totem.xml
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/it/figures/totem_show_playlist_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/it/figures/totem_next_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/it/figures/totem_volume_mute_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/it/figures/totem_volume_maximum_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/it/figures/totem_previous_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/it/figures/totem_start_window.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/it/figures/totem_play_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/it/figures/totem_pause_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/zh_TW/totem.xml
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/zh_TW/figures/totem_show_playlist_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/zh_TW/figures/totem_next_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/zh_TW/figures/totem_volume_mute_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/zh_TW/figures/totem_volume_maximum_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/zh_TW/figures/totem_previous_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/zh_TW/figures/totem_start_window.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/zh_TW/figures/totem_play_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/zh_TW/figures/totem_pause_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/te/totem.xml
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/te/figures/totem_show_playlist_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/te/figures/totem_next_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/te/figures/totem_volume_mute_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/te/figures/totem_volume_maximum_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/te/figures/totem_previous_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/te/figures/totem_start_window.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/te/figures/totem_play_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/te/figures/totem_pause_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/ja/totem.xml
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/ja/figures/totem_show_playlist_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/ja/figures/totem_next_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/ja/figures/totem_volume_mute_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/ja/figures/totem_volume_maximum_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/ja/figures/totem_previous_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/ja/figures/totem_start_window.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/ja/figures/totem_play_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/ja/figures/totem_pause_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/de/totem.xml
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/de/figures/totem_show_playlist_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/de/figures/totem_next_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/de/figures/totem_volume_mute_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/de/figures/totem_volume_maximum_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/de/figures/totem_previous_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/de/figures/totem_start_window.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/de/figures/totem_play_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/de/figures/totem_pause_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/bg/totem.xml
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/bg/figures/totem_show_playlist_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/bg/figures/totem_next_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/bg/figures/totem_volume_mute_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/bg/figures/totem_volume_maximum_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/bg/figures/totem_previous_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/bg/figures/totem_start_window.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/bg/figures/totem_play_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/bg/figures/totem_pause_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/el/totem.xml
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/el/figures/totem_show_playlist_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/el/figures/totem_next_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/el/figures/totem_volume_mute_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/el/figures/totem_volume_maximum_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/el/figures/totem_previous_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/el/figures/totem_start_window.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/el/figures/totem_play_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/el/figures/totem_pause_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/ru/totem.xml
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/ru/figures/totem_show_playlist_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/ru/figures/totem_next_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/ru/figures/totem_volume_mute_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/ru/figures/totem_volume_maximum_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/ru/figures/totem_previous_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/ru/figures/totem_start_window.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/ru/figures/totem_play_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/ru/figures/totem_pause_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/oc/totem.xml
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/oc/figures/totem_show_playlist_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/oc/figures/totem_next_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/oc/figures/totem_volume_mute_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/oc/figures/totem_volume_maximum_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/oc/figures/totem_previous_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/oc/figures/totem_start_window.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/oc/figures/totem_play_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/oc/figures/totem_pause_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/fr/totem.xml
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/fr/figures/totem_show_playlist_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/fr/figures/totem_next_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/fr/figures/totem_volume_mute_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/fr/figures/totem_volume_maximum_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/fr/figures/totem_previous_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/fr/figures/totem_start_window.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/fr/figures/totem_play_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/fr/figures/totem_pause_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/en_GB/totem.xml
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/en_GB/figures/totem_show_playlist_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/en_GB/figures/totem_next_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/en_GB/figures/totem_volume_mute_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/en_GB/figures/totem_volume_maximum_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/en_GB/figures/totem_previous_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/en_GB/figures/totem_start_window.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/en_GB/figures/totem_play_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/en_GB/figures/totem_pause_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/es/totem.xml
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/es/figures/totem_show_playlist_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/es/figures/totem_next_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/es/figures/totem_volume_mute_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/es/figures/totem_volume_maximum_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/es/figures/totem_previous_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/es/figures/totem_start_window.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/es/figures/totem_play_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/es/figures/totem_pause_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/sv/totem.xml
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/sv/figures/totem_show_playlist_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/sv/figures/totem_next_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/sv/figures/totem_volume_mute_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/sv/figures/totem_volume_maximum_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/sv/figures/totem_previous_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/sv/figures/totem_start_window.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/sv/figures/totem_play_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/sv/figures/totem_pause_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/ro/totem.xml
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/ro/figures/totem_show_playlist_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/ro/figures/totem_next_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/ro/figures/totem_volume_mute_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/ro/figures/totem_volume_maximum_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/ro/figures/totem_previous_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/ro/figures/totem_start_window.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/ro/figures/totem_play_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/ro/figures/totem_pause_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/da/totem.xml
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/da/figures/totem_show_playlist_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/da/figures/totem_next_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/da/figures/totem_volume_mute_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/da/figures/totem_volume_maximum_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/da/figures/totem_previous_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/da/figures/totem_start_window.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/da/figures/totem_play_button.png
/usr/share/gnome/help/totem/da/figures/totem_pause_button.png
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The doc link solved my last open question: *“C” for the default (English) documents* :)